# How does Actionscript choose which order to run objects' code in?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, gameobject

I can only assume that Flash runs code in the order that objects were created - so newer objects are run later. Is this true?

Is there any way, other than deleting and recreating objects, that I can change this order?

Answer (score 1):

If your are working on Flash or Adobe Animate area, change the depth of your MovieClips to change the order of running them by select and press ctrl+shift+(UP or DOWN).